# Objective-C Pod doesn't read code properly from .swift files

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm using ObjC pod in my Swift project.

I import the library in my .swift file.

The ObjC project have Delegate and DataSource.

I implement the methods for use without any errors, but when I build and run the project, the app crashes with error that the methods of the DataSource has not been implemented.

`reason: ''numberOfContacts' Not implemented'`

It looks like the ObjC pod doesn't read the implemented methods in my .swift file.

It executes this line:

```
- (NSInteger)mev_horizontalContactsNumberOfContacts
{
    if ([_dataSource respondsToSelector:@selector(numberOfContacts)]) {
        return [_dataSource numberOfContacts];
    } else {
        NSAssert([_dataSource respondsToSelector:@selector(numberOfContacts)], @"'numberOfContacts' Not implemented");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is the pod: https://github.com/manuelescrig/MEVHorizontalContacts

Answer (score 0):

Check if your pod file has `use_frameworks!`, if Yes, then just import of `YOUR_OBJC_SDK` will work.

```
// Podfile
use_frameworks!
pod 'YOUR_OBJC_SDK'
```

If it doesn't have `use_frameworks!`, then you may need to add the `Bridging-Header` to `import` all the `ObjectiveC` framework.

Goto `Swift Compiler - Code Generation` in your project **Build Settings**. Add the path of your bridging header file next to `Objective C Bridging Header` from the project root folder. It should be `Your_Project/YOUR_Bridging-Header.h` file.

Comment: it have use_frameworks! also I tried with Bridging-Header, but still crash... Swift 5 Xcode 11

Comment: Can you paste your Bridging-Header file? check my updated answer for adding header file in build settings.

Comment: #ifndef Header_h
#define Header_h
#import "MEVHorizontalContacts.h"

#endif

Comment: did you try to add the header file in build settings?

Comment: I didn't create this project I downloaded it from GitHub and added MEVHorizontalContactsDelegate, MEVHorizontalContactsDataSource in my class. Then I added the methods that require the using of MEVHorizontalContacts.
func numberOfContacts() -> Int {...} , func contact(at index: Int) -> MEVHorizontalContactsCell! {...} , func contactSelected(at index: Int) {...} , func numberOfItems(atContactIndex index: Int) -> Int {...} , func item(_ item: Int, atContactIndex index: Int) -> MEVHorizontalContactsCell! {...} , func item(_ item: Int, selectedAtContactIndex index: Int) {...}